# Flexible filter for data frame in R

Tags: r, select, filter

I need to filter one data frame using information from another. Names and number of columns could vary, as the number of conditions used for selection. For example the data frame that I would like to select from has the following structure:

```
name   info_1    info_2  info_3 info_4  value 
var1    aa       123       bb     xx1   120
var2    bb       345       cc     xx2   520
var3    aa       122       cc     xx1   640
var4    dd       345       dd     xx3   540
...
```

and data frame with information for filters:

```
info_1  info_3  info_4
   aa      bb    xx1
   bb      cc    N/A
   dd      N/A   N/A
...
```

Number of columns in first data frame and number of columns that should be used for filters could be different for different data sets. 
Is there is effective way to do such filtering? I think the filtering could be done in for loop for each column, however obviously it is not most efficient way to do.

Comment: What is your expected output based on the example showed?  The `filter`ing means which values you want to keep/delete etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are certainly looking for:

```
df[Reduce('&', Map(function(u,v) v%in%u, filtering_df, df[names(filtering_df)])),]

#  name info_1 info_2 info_3 info_4 value
#1 var1     aa    123     bb    xx1   120
#3 var3     aa    122     cc    xx1   640
```

Comment: I suspect this could be solved more elegantly with a join operation, but who knows ... The expected result is not clear.

Comment: Thank you very much! This is what I was looking for.